# Socket closed unexpectedly, django channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему я не могу подключиться к веб сокету, следуя данному туториалу
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/

Настроил всё как в примере, только у меня всё развернуто в докере. Сайт запускается, всё работает, но к сокету нет коннекта.

**У меня приложение app**

settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',
    ...

    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'channels',

    'chat',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "app.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
}
```

}

app/routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {"websocket": URLRouter(chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)}
)
```

chat/routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Comment: что такое `routing.py`?

Comment: что в логах? (возможно придется убрать из проекта djangodebugtoolbar так как он съедает логи djanog channels)

Comment: @Антон в логах ошибок нет, просто нет коннекта к сокету

Comment: @finally это маршрутизация для веб сокетов